# strings as features in decision tree/random forest

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am new to machine learning!

Right now I am doing some problems on application of decision tree/random forest. I am trying to fit a problem which has numbers as well as strings (such as country name) as features. Now the library, scikit-learn takes only numbers as parameters, but I want to inject the strings as well as they carry significant amount of knowledge.

How do I handle such scenario, I can convert string to numbers by some mechanism such as hashing in python. But I would like to know the best practice on how strings are handled in decision tree problems.

Answer (score 5):

1) How to add "strings" as features.

Very few algorithms can natively handle strings in any form, and decision trees are not one of them. You have to convert them to something that the decision tree knows about (generally numeric or categorical variables).

How to convert them to features: This very much depends on the nature of the strings. If the strings are sentences, you can use things like [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) to map each word to a numeric feature. There are numerous different strategies for determining what numeric value to use, but just using 0/1 for not present / present is often a decent baseline.

For countries, this doesn't make sense as you're representing your feature in the wrong way. A country is more akin to a categorical variable. There are only X countries and you must have a value that is in X (this may not be strictly absolutely true, but that's beyond the point). scikit-learn doesn't have support for categorical variables. You can "fake" it by using a [one-hot-encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), but it likely will not work quite as well as a library that fully supports categorical variables.

Note that just because countries can be represented as categories doesn't mean that it is the best way to handle them. It depends highly on what your data is and what you are doing. No one can answer it for you without knowing all the details.

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle your problem is to use Breiman's `randomForest` implementation in R.  This implementation would allow you to use actual strings as inputs.  For example, you could include a string `country` column in your input data frame.  The resulting model would be built assuming that the only values for `country` were the ones in your training data.  One other cool thing which `randomForest` in R can offer is something called partial dependence plots.  The R function is called `partialPlot`, and it generates a plot showing how your **response** variable (i.e. what you are trying to predict) depends on a certain predictor.  In the case of `country`, you could actually generate a plot which shows how your response varies depending on the `country` you choose.

The answer by Raff Edward also makes sense in the case where you don't want to use your strings directly.  One example of this might be where you have as input people's names as strings.  However, you are really interested (for whatever reason) in how the **length** of a person's name influences your response variable.  In this case, you would just take `nchar(name)`, where `name` is the vector containing the name strings.

To get started using `randomForest` in R, you can visit [this site](http://www.r-project.org/) to download it.  It's free for personal use, and I don't believe we paid for it either when I used it at work a few years ago.

There is just one more step you need to get started.  You have to install the `randomForest` package into your R console.  You can do that by typing:

```
install.packages("randomForest")
```

If you have an active internet connection, the R console should be able to resolve that request and prompt you with a list of mirrors from which to choose.

There is a wealth of sites on how to use `randomForest` and `partialPlot` which you access by Googling for these terms.